# How do we validate the format of the CSR using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, csr

I'm currently trying to validate a CSRformat via javascript regex and I'm currently stuck with this regex:

```
^ (-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----)(.*[\r\ n]) + (-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----) $
```

What I want to accomplish is that I need to validate only the 1st occurence of the

```
-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

and

```
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

so anything below except white spaces or enter spaces becomes invalid.

This must be invalid as well:

```html
    -----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
test
test
test
test
    -----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
    -----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
test
test
test
test
    -----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

it should only be:

```js
    -----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
test
test
test
test
    -----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Looks like I'm getting a hard time as well to figure this out via RegEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this version of regex that will capture **only the first *START/END* block** only in case it is a unique block of this kind:

```
^(?:(?!-{3,}(?:BEGIN|END) NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST)[\s\S])*(-{3,}BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST(?:(?!-{3,}END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST)[\s\S])*?-{3,}END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-{3,})(?![\s\S]*?-{3,}BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST[\s\S]+?-{3,}END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST[\s\S]*?$)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qV4cO5/2)

**EDIT**:

To make sure we just match at the end, with optional spaces, you can use a shorter regex:

```
^(?:(?!-{3,}(?:BEGIN|END) NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST)[\s\S])*(-{3,}BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST(?:(?!-{3,}BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST)[\s\S])*?-{3,}END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-{3,})\s*$
```

See [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/qV4cO5/3)

Comment: I also tested this and I think this has also same results -- I think I need to update my question though -- the regex must also be invalid if it repeats the BEGIN and END tags

Comment: @MarkBautista: Please check another update. If it works for you, I will provide more explanation of the regex used. Also, feel free to fork my demo on regex101 with your examples.

Comment: fantastic! Cool answer!

i did some minor modifications as I realize it must be 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST' / 'END CERTIFICATE REQUEST' (without 'NEW')

Answer (score 1):

Try with that regex:

```
^(?:\s|\R)*(?:-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----)(?<request>(?:.*\R)+)(?:-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----)(?:\s|\R)*$
```

[Test it there](https://regex101.com/r/vS8vR2/1)

Comment: I also tested this and I think this has also same results -- I think I need to update my question though -- the regex must also be invalid if it repeats the BEGIN and END tags

Answer (score 0):

While the RegEx check is useful, it would be better to actually try to decode the certificate.

Here is an example of doing that:

https://pkijs.org/examples/PKCS10_complex_example.html