# How to validate an SSL Certificate

Tags: regex, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a form that users can enter in a copy of their SSL certificate. Users tend to just enter comments instead of the actual certificate. What would the regex syntax be that I can use to ensure they are entering a valid certificate?

Comment: Have a look at one. It should start with a line containing a lot of hyphens and the words BEGIN CERTIFICATE.

Comment: I realize that... I am not an expert in regex; hence the reason I am asking for help with the regex syntax

Comment: Why wouldn't you use something like [this](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) to validate SSL certificates?

Comment: You don't *need* a regular expression. You just need to check for that header, and the footer if you like. A regex for that would be the header line followed by `.*` followed by the footer line. But no regex can completely validate a certificate. It just isn't that kind of problem.

Comment: The form field is actually part of WHMCS so configuration is done in it. I am able to add a regex to the field and WHMCS will validate it.  That being said... I can not add a bunch of extra code.

Comment: @Erutan409 Because that site requires a certificate to be already installed on a public web server.

Answer (score 5):

The below regular expression will help you to validate a custom field in WHMCS that requires a valid certificate structure.

```
/^(?:(?!-{3,}(?:BEGIN|END) CERTIFICATE)[\s\S])*(-{3,}BEGIN CERTIFICATE(?:(?!-{3,}END CERTIFICATE)[\s\S])*?-{3,}END CERTIFICATE-{3,})(?![\s\S]*?-{3,}BEGIN CERTIFICATE[\s\S]+?-{3,}END CERTIFICATE[\s\S]*?$)/
```

Simply paste that in to the *Validation* field.

I modified the regular expression found on [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30322983).

The regular expression from that question can also be used if you have a custom field requiring a Certificate Signing Request:

```
/^(?:(?!-{3,}(?:BEGIN|END) NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST)[\s\S])*(-{3,}BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST(?:(?!-{3,}END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST)[\s\S])*?-{3,}END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-{3,})(?![\s\S]*?-{3,}BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST[\s\S]+?-{3,}END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST[\s\S]*?$)/
```

Answer (score 1):

> What would the regex syntax be that I can use to ensure they are entering a valid certificate?

There isn't one. Certificate validity depends on expiry date, the integrity of a digital signature, and the validity of the signer's own certificate. No regular expression can check all that.

If on the other hand you just want to reject outright garbage, see my comments under your question.

Comment: I am only looking to limit outright garbage... As per my comment above, due to having to work with WHMCS, I have to use regex and can't create custom code